# Object or Array to store this data

Tags: java, arrays, object

So, if you have data like this:

```
site.name = "domain"
site.url = "http://www.domain.com"
site.color = "red"
site.author = "name"
```

And you have a bunch of different sites, would you store this data in an object or array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a job for an object.

```
class Site
{

 String name;
 String url;
 String color;
 String author;

 Site(String name,String url, String color, String author)
 {
   this.name=name;
   this.url=url;
   this.color=color;
   this.author=author;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Vigrant wrote, Site should almost certainly be an object.

As for how to store a bunch of Sites, an array is possible, but you should consider some form of Collection, perhaps a Map, so you can quickly access a Site given the name.

e.g.

```
Map<String, Site> sitesByName = new HashMap<String, Site>();
```

(Note - this only works if all sites have a *unique* name.  Using the URL as a key is a safer alternative)

Answer (score 0):

I guess array of objects will be good to go